# Difference between Kilogram-weight and mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, weight

I got really confused about this $\text{kg-wt}$ and mass when I went through a question which says

> A body weighs $700\text{ kg-wt}$ on Earth surface. How much will it weigh on the surface of a planet whose mass is $1/7$ and radius is half those of the Earth?

Here should I consider $700$ as mass of the given body i.e, $m=700\text{ kg}$ or should I say $\text{weight}=mg=700$?

Comment: Weight is force which affects body due to gravitational pull on it and it is measured in Newtons. Mass is a measure of how good body can keep it's inertial properties,- i.e. "wish strength" for keeping same linear speed upon influence of constant force and it is measured in $\text{kg}$ in IS system.

Comment: It is confusing notation. I wish we could stick with **mass** in kg, but the "social inertia" of the common meaning of kg, pound, etc.  is pretty large.

Answer (score 3):

One kilogram-weight is the force of gravity felt on Earth by a mass of 1 kg.

Therefore, a mass that has a weight (a unit of force) of $700  \text{ kg}_w$ has a mass of $700 \text{ kg}$. The mass remains the same in the entire universe. The gravitational force in newtons is
$$1 \text{ kg}_w= 1 \text{ kg}\cdot g=9.8 \text{ N}$$
where $g\simeq 9.8$ on Earth.

Now you have to calculate the force felt by that object on the other planet. To do this you use $mg_{\text{new}}$ where $g_{\text{new}}$ is the gravitational acceleration on the other planet. Recall that
$$g_{\text{new}}=G\frac{M_\text{new}}{r^2_\text{new}}=g\frac
{M_\text{new}}{M_\text{Earth}}\frac{r^2_\text{Earth}}{r^2_{\text{new}}}$$

Then the desired answer is
$$\boxed{700\text{ kg}\cdot g_{\text{new}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

> A body weights 700kgwt on earth surface.

This statement means that the weight of the body is equal to that of a 700 kg mass.
So, you should consider the mass of the body to be 700 kg

Answer (score 0):

The weight of a mass depends on these formulas: see link below.

The mass is a measurement of the amount of stuff like protons, neutrons and electrons.
In the two formulas below the mass (m) which is the inertial mass stays the same.
On the smaller planet (M) is 1/7 the mass of Earth and (r) is 1/2 the radius of Earth.
You can measure the inertial mass on either planet or even in space by placing it on a spring and measuring the oscillation period. Equal masses will always have equal oscillations.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4AaF.jpg

Answer (score -2):

As long as the body stays on the Earth, it is irrelevant. What the statement really says is $m=$ 700 kg.

Comment: Do you mean mass $m$ as composition of the body? If so, the composition or matter of a body doesn't change anywhere in the universe not only on the Earth.